# mac server ssh change port

Tags: ssh, osx-snow-leopard

this works for snow leopard desktop but not for snow leopard server. why?

```
   <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Listeners</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>22022</string>
                    <key>SockFamily</key>
                    <string>IPv4</string>
                    <key>Bonjour</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>22022</string>
                            <string>sftp-ssh</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I tested it.  I assume you've edited this in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist, and then reloaded it with:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

BTW, you probably shouldn't change the entry in the Bonjour service array from "ssh" to "22022" -- that's the name the service gets advertised under, not the port number; you're offering the ssh service on port 22022, not the 22022 service.